# gradle "package does not exist"

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am using idea and gradle to develop a multi-module project. one module uses the classes of another and the idea finds them, but when building with a gradle, a compilation error occurs and a "package does not exist" error. this project runs fine on another computer, so there are no errors in build.gradle. I tried literally everything I found on the Internet. i am using idea 2019.3 and gradle 4.9.

Comment: Do you get the same error when building from command line outside IDE?

Comment: @y.bedrov yes, i do

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example for investigation?

Comment: @y.bedrov i'm sorry but it's impossible. But i already told that project works fine on another PC. Issue somewhere else.